# Android: how to programmatically set width of ImageView inside TableRow

Tags: android, android-layout

How do you programmatically set the width of an ImageView inside a TableRow? I do NOT want the cell width to change, only the width of the image inside the cell.

*Layout: (The ellipsis are there to reduce the code)*

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TableRow android:gravity="center_vertical">
<Button>...</Button>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fruit"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:src="@drawable/apple"
    android:scaleType="matrix"
></ImageView>
<Button>...</Button>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>...</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

*Java:*

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fruit);
LayoutParams frame = iv.getLayoutParams();
frame.width = 100;
iv.setLayoutParams(frame);
```

---

**EDIT**: i want the image to be cropped inside the bounds i set and have the table cell be the original width. Below is the code example that worked for me thanks to parag's suggestion:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() , R.drawable.apple); 
int width = 50;
int height = 44; 
Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, iv.getScrollX(), iv.getScrollY(), width, height);
iv.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Another way that  u resized the bitmap

```
    ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sc01);
    int width=200;
    int height=200;
    Bitmap resizedbitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
    img.setImageBitmap(resizedbitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to scale the image? Or crop it?

To scale, try ImageView.[setImageMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) and Matrix.[preScale](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#preScale%28float,%20float%29).

If you don't want to figure out the Matrices, you could try Rects (bounding boxes). Get the original rect with ImageView.[getDrawingRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingRect%28android.graphics.Rect%29) and then define whatever Rect you want and use Matrix.[setRectToRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect%28android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit%29) to create your image matrix.

Otherwise, have you tried ImageView.[setMaxWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setMaxWidth%28int%29)?

Comment: setMaxWidth didnt work. I tried your suggestion, but Matrix.setRectToRect requires a Bitmap.Config which scales the image.