# How to change width height of a bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

In my application I have to get a bitmap and then change the width of this bitmap by multiplying it with 3/4.
What is the best possible way of doing this ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4813072/645270) might help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android/10703256#10703256

Comment: @Keyser  can you tell me what's the filter for and should I set it true or false?

Comment: [what the filter does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895065/what-does-the-filter-parameter-to-createscaledbitmap-do)