# Set Height and Width of FrameLayout based on Bitmap

Tags: android, exception

I'm trying to set the `FrameLayout`'s width and height based on a `Bitmap`, what I did was below

```
        Bitmap theBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(theFileImage.toString());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(theBitmap.getWidth(), theBitmap.getHeight());
        frame.setLayoutParams(lp);
        image.setLayoutParams(lp);
        image.setImageBitmap(theBitmap);
```

but I'm getting a `ClassCastException`.

What did I do wrong?

Edited:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

Comment: stab in the dark but try changing 'LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp' to 'RelativeLayout.LayoutParams'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For setting Layout params, you need to use the inner class LayoutParams of its parent.

For Example : If you are having a LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout and if you need to set the layout params of Linear Layout, you need to use the LayoutParams inner class of RelativeLayout. Else it will gives a ClassCastException.

So in your case, for setting the FrameLayout's Layoutparams , you need to use its parent Layout's Layout Params. Suppose if your layout is like :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code :

```
    FrameLayout frame=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.flContainer);  
    ImageView image=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bitmap theBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(theFileImage.toString());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(theBitmap.getWidth(), theBitmap.getHeight());
    frame.setLayoutParams(lp);
    image.setImageBitmap(theBitmap);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error. FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 17:50:24.387: E/AndroidRuntime(5325):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:941)

Comment: If your image view is inside the frame layout, try removing the code to set layout params for image view. Check the updated answer and let me know.

Comment: And the FrameLayout's Layout perfectly fits on the Bitmap.

Comment: Question, how do i Set the image to that of the LinearLayout? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811905/android-how-to-programmatically-set-width-of-imageview-inside-tablerow (Please help... thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the `ClassCastException` I assume you are doing something illegal here, a couple of questions, what are **frame** and **image**?

If frame is a reference to FrameLayout the you would have  to use

`FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(theBitmap.getWidth(), theBitmap.getHeight());`

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: frame is a FrameLayout while image is an ImageView.

Comment: Ok so is your main container Layout a FrameLayout or a LinearLayout?

Comment: The parent is a RelativeLayout, FrameLayout is its child, while ImageView is the child of FrameLayout.

Comment: and I'm also gettings this new error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 17:35:54.148: E/AndroidRuntime(32516):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:941)