# Android: How to programatically set the width of a tablerow background

Tags: java, android

To clarify my question:
I have  a tablelayout with some tablerows in it. Each table row only has a textview in it.

What I want to do is have the background of the tablerow act as a progress bar for that particular tablerow. Is there any way to essentially have a progress bar as a background for a tablerow?

Comment: You can extend the ProgressBar class to add text in front of it.  Here's an [example](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/23/android-progressbar-with-text/)  Simply place this view in the TableRow and make adjustments as needed.

Comment: If you don't want to work with ProgressBar, you can programatically set the width with ImageView as the background of the cell.  [Example of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811905/android-how-to-programmatically-set-width-of-imageview-inside-tablerow?rq=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

1. You can extend the ProgressBar class to add text in front of it. Here's an [example.](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/23/android-progressbar-with-text/) Simply place this view in the TableRow and make adjustments as needed.
2. You can programatically set the width with ImageView as the background of the cell. Example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811905/android-how-to-programmatically-set-width-of-imageview-inside-tablerow?rq=1).

I'd try #2 first, as it seems the most straightforward and no extra classes.

Comment: Thank you, option 1 ended up being a better choice, haha. I couldn't figure out option 2 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

With `FrameView`, you can have two views, the first one serving as a background, and the second one, with a transparent background, drawn on top of it.

For example, here's a sandwich made from a camera preview, a semi-transparent layer (initially invisible), and a relative layout whose children are drawn on top:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/transparency"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#80000000"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ontop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        ...
    </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```